# Вывод сообщения под иконкой расширения

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Единственная функция - вывод сообщения под иконкой расширения. Происходит это разными способами:

1. при запуске браузера
2. при нажатии на саму иконку
3. при переходе на определенную страницу

Первый срабатывает, а вот следующие выдают ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBadgeText' of undefined
```

*Прошу помощи. Заранее благодарен*

**[ manifest.json ]**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "description": "description",

    "permissions": ["http://google.ru/*", "http://yandex.ru/*"],

    "browser_action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },

    "background": { "page": "popup.html" },

    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["https://www.google.ru/*", "https://yandex.ru/*"],
        "js": [ "script.js" ]
    }]
}
```

**[ popup.html ]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>html { width: 500px; height: 300px; }</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ script.js ]**

```
var amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
alert(amount);
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: amount.toString() });
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Первый срабатывает, а вот следующий выдают ошибку

При нажатии на иконку значения меняются как и должны, а ошибка происходит в третьем варианте, в результате вызова `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` из `content_scripts`, так как `content_scripts`

```
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches": ["https://www.google.ru/*", "https://yandex.ru/*"],
    "js": [ "script.js" ]
}]
```

не имеет доступа к `chrome.*` api.

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
>   - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )
>   - i18n
>   - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
>   - storage
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

Ошибка будет выводиться только в консоль страниц, которые удовлетворяют `matches`.

Эти действия нужно выполнять в `background`. Первые два способа работают из-за того, что в `popup.html` подключен `scripts.js`, а он имеет доступ к нужному функционалу.

Если нужно, чтобы значения менялись в зависимости от `URL`, можно воспользоваться событием `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`.

Это событие, которое срабатывает в момент обновления вкладки, в `callback`'е события можно получать данные вкладок и отслеживать нужные `URL`, в нем же можно выполнять необходимые действия для установки нужных значений.

[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) | [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) | [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-on..)